# How to use mtpro2 in Overleaf?

Tags: packages, overleaf, mtpro

I bought the mtpro2 full package and I use it in my local editor. I have all the files (a lot: .pfm, .map, .sty, .pfb...) that they send when you buy the package in order to use it properly. I want to know if I can upload all those files (or just the necessary ones) and use it in Overleaf from any computer. I've tried to do it and using the same preamble as in my local editor, but doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... If you have `OTF` fonts of `mtpro`, then I'll guide you how to use it in `overleaf`

Comment: @ingmar I don't think the duplicate is correct, that one is for lite version only (I recently edited the title, but on careful reading of the question and the answer you can see it covers lite version usage)

Comment: I guess there's [Can I use my own classes and packages in ShareLaTex or Overleaf - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330189/can-i-use-my-own-classes-and-packages-in-sharelatex-or-overleaf) but that only cover "text" files i.e. TeX source code (not font files)

Comment: There's also [pdftex - Getting pdflatex to find fonts in the same directory as the LaTeX source file - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185511/getting-pdflatex-to-find-fonts-in-the-same-directory-as-the-latex-source-file) but I don't know if it applies on overleaf or not.

Comment: @MadyYuvi I would appreciate your assistance